# Building CyanogenMod 13: customizing build.prop via makefile

Tags: makefile, build, cyanogenmod

Following [this](https://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Build_for_angler) guide on CM Wiki, I've been compiling CM for my own devices for more than a year now, but that does nothing more than recreating nightly builds. I always wanted to venture beyond the basics and today I got my hands on making some first steps.

What I'm planning to do right now is to customize `/system/build.prop` prior to building, as opposed to modifying it after flashing. I did some research and identified some scripts and makefiles responsible for generating it, and the one makefile in question is `vendor/cm/config/common.mk`. The section I'm looking to modify alters the "CyanogenMod version" field displayed in Settings-About, as in the pic below:

[image: SAMPLE]

`common.mk` has these lines corresponding to it (slightly modified to shorten):

```
ifeq ($(CM_BUILDTYPE), RELEASE)
    ifndef TARGET_VENDOR_RELEASE_BUILD_ID
        CM_VERSION := $(PRODUCT_VERSION_MAJOR).$(PRODUCT_VERSION_MINOR).$(PRODUCT_VERSION_MAINTENANCE)$(PRODUCT_VERSION_DEVICE_SPECIFIC)-$(CM_BUILD)
    else
        ifeq ($(TARGET_BUILD_VARIANT),user)
            ifeq ($(CM_VERSION_MAINTENANCE),0)
                CM_VERSION := $(PRODUCT_VERSION_MAJOR).$(PRODUCT_VERSION_MINOR)-$(TARGET_VENDOR_RELEASE_BUILD_ID)-$(CM_BUILD)
            else
                CM_VERSION := $(PRODUCT_VERSION_MAJOR).$(PRODUCT_VERSION_MINOR).$(CM_VERSION_MAINTENANCE)-$(TARGET_VENDOR_RELEASE_BUILD_ID)-$(CM_BUILD)
            endif
        else
            CM_VERSION := $(PRODUCT_VERSION_MAJOR).$(PRODUCT_VERSION_MINOR).$(PRODUCT_VERSION_MAINTENANCE)$(PRODUCT_VERSION_DEVICE_SPECIFIC)-$(CM_BUILD)
        endif
    endif
else
    ifeq ($(CM_VERSION_MAINTENANCE),0)
        CM_VERSION := $(PRODUCT_VERSION_MAJOR).$(PRODUCT_VERSION_MINOR)-$(shell date -u +%Y%m%d)-$(CM_BUILDTYPE)$(CM_EXTRAVERSION)-$(CM_BUILD)
    else
        CM_VERSION := $(PRODUCT_VERSION_MAJOR).$(PRODUCT_VERSION_MINOR).$(CM_VERSION_MAINTENANCE)-$(shell date -u +%Y%m%d)-$(CM_BUILDTYPE)$(CM_EXTRAVERSION)-$(CM_BUILD)
    endif
endif

PRODUCT_PROPERTY_OVERRIDES += \
  ro.cm.version=$(CM_VERSION) \
  ro.cm.releasetype=$(CM_BUILDTYPE) \
  ro.modversion=$(CM_VERSION) \
  ro.cm.display.version=$(CM_VERSION)
```

Now I want to define another **variable with space** that stores the custom string that I want to display in that field, for example "CM13 FOO BAR", so I'd write this:

```
ifndef CM_VERSION_CUSTOM
    CM_VERSION_CUSTOM := CM13 FOO BAR
endif
```

...and assign CM_VERSION_CUSTOM to where CM_VERSION applies.

In practise this doesn't work at all - the string was outputted to `/build.prop` incorrectly, sometimes as if each space is a newline, sometimes as if the contents after the 1st space doesn't exist, like this:

```
ro.cm.version=CM13
FOO
BAR
ro.modversion=CM13
ro.cm.display.version=CM13
```

I tried adding quotes (' and " tested), either to the string definition or to where CM_VERSION CUSTOM was referenced (like "$(CM_VERSION_CUSTOM)"), but none helped. I'm not familiar with makefile at all, so I'm at a loss right now. Can someone point me in the right way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just writing a shell script for the purpose. I package the script inside a flashable zip and let updater-script call the script. The script itself goes something like this:

```
#!/sbin/sh

CM_VER="CyanogenMod 12.1 Nightly CGMod"
sed -i "s/ro.cm.version=.*/ro.cm.version=$CM_VER/g" /system/build.prop
```

This not only allows me to modify this property, but also others like build type, date and others (with the help of `grep`) that are hard to touch before building.